# Make alexa/amazon echo say, what I type

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have an echo dot (Alexa) and I would like to control what the alexa is saying from my computer (by typing it). I can synthesize speach using amazon polly, but can I also make Alexa say it *and* enable the blue glow while she is saying it as if she would respond to a voice command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can add capabilities to Alexa. These additional capabilities are called Alexa Skills. Please go through the following documentation for building Alexa skills using Alexa Skills Kit(ASK).

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/ask-overviews/build-skills-with-the-alexa-skills-kit.html

**EDIT:**

Alexa is basically based on the user-initiated conversation, hence it getting invoke without the user initiating a conversation defeats the whole purpose of it. However, [Alexa Communications Announcements](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/acm/announcements-acm.html) might be the very thing you are looking for. As it allows you to send announcements to you Alexa device using the companion app. It says,

Use the Alexa app on a mobile device to send recorded audio or TTS announcements.

> From the Communicate tab of the app, select the Announce button. Then
>   use either the microphone button to record an audio announcement
>   (which will play in the user's voice) or the keyboard to write a text
>   announcement (which will play in Alexa's voice).

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: As fas as I can tell, skills only allow me to add reactions and functionality to things the user says to alexa. That is not what I want. I want to type on a different device and make alexa say something _without_ anyone talking to it. Or am I missing something from the documentation?

Comment: Please look at the solution in the Edit, that should do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I did this using a node server and socket.io npm package.  It basically called the web server with an api call (Socket.io request) each time you asked alexa a question and then you could type the response and that would be returned to alexa and spoken outloud.  You need to initiate the conversation by talking to alexa because you cannot push notifications to alexa.  But Alexa will wait a long time for an API call to complete before answering so you could wait minutes before sending your socket.io response.  (Alexa only waits 6 seconds for a human to respond after a prompt but she'll wait until your lambda times out for an API to return)

here's a link to the video on linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/posts/calebgates_i-build-a-lot-of-amazon-alexa-skills-so-activity-6491027705448923136-EzPI